# PIG CqlStorage not working with Integers

Tags: apache-pig, cql3, datastax-enterprise, datastax, cqlsh

I am running the Pig example from DataStax: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/about_pig#pig-read-write. I am using DataStax Enterprise 3.1.2. But when I want to save the Data back in Cassandra with:

```
grunt> STORE insertformat INTO
   'cql://cql3ks/test?output_query=UPDATE+cql3ks.test+set+b+%3D+%3F'
   USING CqlStorage;
```

I get the following output:

```
2014-03-11 10:14:38,383 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-03-11 10:14:38,440 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-03-11 10:14:38,442 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-03-11 10:14:38,442 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-03-11 10:14:38,451 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-03-11 10:14:38,452 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-03-11 10:14:38,452 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job1332293282461754849.jar
2014-03-11 10:14:40,560 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job1332293282461754849.jar created
2014-03-11 10:14:40,569 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2014-03-11 10:14:40,597 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2014-03-11 10:14:41,111 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2014-03-11 10:14:43,934 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2014-03-11 10:14:45,547 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_201403091619_0036
2014-03-11 10:14:45,547 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - More information at: http://127.0.0.1:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201403091619_0036
2014-03-11 10:17:52,330 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201403091619_0036 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-03-11 10:17:52,330 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2014-03-11 10:17:52,334 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 4 or 0 byte int (11))
2014-03-11 10:17:52,335 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-03-11 10:17:52,335 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
1.0.4.8 0.9.2   root    2014-03-11 10:14:38     2014-03-11 10:17:52     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201403091619_0036   insertformat,moretestvalues     MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed! Error - # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201403091619_0036_m_000000      cql://cql3ks/test?output_query=UPDATE+cql3ks.test+set+b+%3D+%3F,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "cql://cql3ks/moredata/"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "cql://cql3ks/test?output_query=UPDATE+cql3ks.test+set+b+%3D+%3F"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201403091619_0036


2014-03-11 10:17:52,335 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
```

The Log-File is:

```
Backend error message
---------------------
java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 4 or 0 byte int (11))
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:248)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 4 or 0 byte int (11))
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:41868)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1689)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1674)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:232)
```

What I am doing wrong? For me, it looks like a Bug, because when I use Strings instead of Integers in CQL while creating the Table, the Example works well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in with a fresh install of DSE-3.12, it works for me. You may need to re-install DSE and re-create the tables to test it again.